# Applying for job takes way too long, no indication of running process, ends after almost 1 and half minutes

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

When you click apply to apply for a job, and you enter your cover letter and any other information and you click the save/submit button, the process kind of sits there and the end user doesn't know exactly what is happening - I really thought my screen froze. I waited close to a minute until I got a message that my submission was successful.

Meanwhile, while waiting, there is no UI element such as a progress bar or spinning circle showing me that something is happening. The time it takes to refresh is way too long, causing the candidate to think maybe nothing has happened. This needs to be investigated.

Comment: Thanks for the report. This seems quite intermittent and hard to repro, but we're taking a look at the backend processing for slow code paths. Also, will be adding some kind of visual feedback that the submission is being processed.

Comment: They have actual real wizards working on SO. Cool.

Comment: Stack Overflow Jobs has been sunset, so I'm removing the status-review tag from this question.